# Array de string con imagenes no funciona de forma corecta

Tags: java, array, string, imagen, contador

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente, en el primer for logra ordenar las cartas en cada array perfectamente.
Pero en el siguiente decidi hacer un contador, esto se debe a que las cartas van del 1 al 9.
Como se ve en el codigo, esta carta + i + 1 + .png que seria: carta1.png, carta2.png, etc.
En el segundo for no EXISTE el contador y no logro saber por que. A continuación dejo el codigo.
Reitero por las dudas por si no se entendio, el contador del for que va del 10 hasta el 18 no funciona, solo almacena 1 carta en todos los arrays, esa carta es carta1_1.png.
No almacena cartas de forma correcta como el otro for. carta1.png, carta2.png,etc.
Cualquier consulta que tengan solo digan! Gracias desde ya

```
String[] cartasdispo = new String[53];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        cartasdispo[0]= "/imagenes/cartabocaabajo.png";
        cartasdispo[i + 1] = "/imagenes/carta" + (i + 1) + ".png";
    }

    for (int i = 10; i <= 18; i++) {
        int contador=0;
        contador++;
        cartasdispo[i] = "/imagenes/carta" + (contador) + "_1.png";    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Es porque pone

```
  int contador=0;
```

cada vez por el bucle.  Lo queire afuera (mejor dicho, antes de) el bucle.

Comment: Y como lo soluciono?? Soy nuevo programando y tengo unas limitaciones, intente con un do o un while pero tal vez los use mal ...

Comment: Me percate de como! Muchas gracias, hay una manera de darte prestigo o puntos?

Comment: Si, hace clique en la flecha al lado de me respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

En tu código puedo observar que tienes instrucciones dentro del `for` que deberían estar afuera, la primera es `cartasdispo[0]= "/imagenes/cartabocaabajo.png";`. Esta no tiene consecuencias que se puedan notar, pero asignas lo mismo en cada iteración.

La segunda es `int contador=0;` y es la causa del problema, como lo tienes actualmente el contador siempre tendrá el valor de 1 porque en cada iteración es inicializado en cero y luego incrementado en 1.

A continuación el código sugerido

```
cartasdispo[0]= "/imagenes/cartabocaabajo.png";
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    cartasdispo[i + 1] = "/imagenes/carta" + (i + 1) + ".png";
}

int contador=0;
for (int i = 10; i <= 18; i++) {
    contador++;
    cartasdispo[i] = "/imagenes/carta" + (contador) + "_1.png";    
}
```